# Matrixnorm, "max" function

Tags: normed-spaces

According to my lecture notes, the following equality holds:

$  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ $\max_{x \neq 0}$    $\frac{\|Ax\|_{2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|x\|_{2}}$ = $\max_{x \neq 0}$ $\frac{\|Ax\|_{2}}{\|x\|_{2}}      $

What is done here obviously is to pull out the $1/\sqrt{n}$ out of the first fraction. Intuitively it is also clear that max(c*x ; x $\in$ vectorspace V) = c*max(x; x $\in$ vectorspace V), but how can this be proven?

Comment: @TextGuest c*max(x; x ∈ vectorspace V) What is the definition of it?

Comment: a scalar times the biggest element of the vectorspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c>0$. Then
\begin{align*}
m=\max_{x\in V}\|cx\|
&\Rightarrow \|cx\|\le m \text{ for all } x\in V\\
&\Rightarrow \|x\|\le m/c \text{ for all } x\in V\\
&\Rightarrow \max_{x\in V}\|x\|\le m/c\\
&\Rightarrow c\,\max_{x\in V}\|x\|\le \max_{x\in V}\|cx\|.
\end{align*}
You can prove that $\max_{x\in V}\|cx\|\le c\,\max_{x\in V}\|x\|$ in a similar manner.